# norm function in for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

Is there any way to write below code in Matlab without for loop?

```
for g=1:nn
    u(g)=uu(g)/norm(uu(g),vv(g));
    v(g)=vv(g)/norm(uu(g),vv(g));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are vector, You can do it by point division:

```
 mat = [uu.' vv.'];
 norms = arrayfun(@(idx)norm(mat(idx,:)),1:length(uu)); % like this post https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/172116
 %or instead norms = sqrt(uu.^2 + vv.^2);
 u = uu ./ norms;
 v = vv ./ norms;
```

Comment: what is fabs? there is an error: Undefined function 'fabs' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: uu=[1,2,3,4];
vv=[2,4,6,8]; 
    n = abs(uu - vv);
 u = uu ./ n;
 v = vv ./ n;

Comment: If one runs above code, the output is u=[2,2,2,2] and v=[1,1,1,1] which is not correct